# why arrayList object can't be written into and read from file in my particular case?

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

**Description:**
My program basically reads input from user. The input objects are stored in an arrayList. The arrayList objects are written into a file. Because I want to print out all the input values, I have created `public List<PersonInfo> readFile()` method to read those objects from file.

**Problem:**
If I open the text file in mentioned directory, I see that no data is saved, and that is no data is read either.

What is the reason that objects can't be stored in file and read from file, although I have created appropriate method.

Code:

***My problem is mainly concerned with this class:***

```
public void writeFile(List<PersonInfo> information) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BankFile3.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(information);
        fos.close();
        os.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<PersonInfo> readFile() {

    try {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BankFile3.txt");
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        fis.close();
        is.close();

    //return readFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

Main class:

```
List<PersonInfo> info = new ArrayList<PersonInfo>();
            List<PersonInfo> info2 = new ArrayList<PersonInfo>();
            ReadWrite rw=new ReadWrite();
            rw.writeFile(info);
            info2=rw.readFile();
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("1. Input personal info\n"
                        + "2. Print them out\n"
                        + "3. Transfer credits\n"
                        + "*************"
                        + "*************");
                option1 = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();
                switch (option1) {
                    case 1:
                        PersonInfo personInfo = new PersonInfo();
                        //take the input
                        System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
                        personInfo.setName(input.nextLine());

                        System.out.println("Give ID: ");
                        personInfo.setId(input.nextInt());
                        System.out.println("Input credit: ");
                        personInfo.setCredit(input.nextDouble());
         info.add(personInfo);
                        break;
                    case 2:
          System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("Name\t\tID\t\tCredit");
                        for (PersonInfo pInfo : info) {
                            System.out.println(pInfo);
                        }
                        System.out.println("\t\t.............\n"
                                + "\t\t.............");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //transfer credit
                        System.out.println("To transfer credit between two persons enter 1");
                        System.out.println("To transfer credit within the same persons enter 2");
                        option2 = input.nextInt();
                        input.nextLine();
                        switch (option2) {
                            case 1:
                                System.out.println("Enter the ID of the person you want to withdraw amount from: ");
                                withdraw_id = input.nextInt();

                                System.out.println("Enter withdraw amount: ");
                                withdraw_amount = input.nextDouble();
                   System.out.println("Enter the ID of the person you want to deposit into: ");
                                dep_id = input.nextDouble();
                                //the amount has been withdrawn will be deposited
                         System.out.println("Done!\tTo print them out out choose option 2");
                                break;
                        }
                }

            }
      }
```

Class for setObject:

```
public PersonInfo() {
    this.name = null;
    this.id = 0;
    this.credit = 0;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
...........
............
```

Comment: add `os.drain()` before closing the file when you write the object

Comment: igreen, thank you, but why should I? you can also see that my method for reading from file isn't very reliablel I guess. Because I have returned null. How could it be improved?

Comment: first, When you write to file before colsing it you should flush all the buffers.
second, When you read from the file iterate on the lines untile you get null.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<PersonInfo> info = new ArrayList<PersonInfo>();
        >> After initialization no values are added to list(ie for info         list object). So list should be empty.
        ReadWrite rw=new ReadWrite();
        rw.writeFile(info);
        >> Just info object available without any values.
        info2=rw.readFile();
       >> returns null by default
```

Comment: Mohan Raj, sorry! Didn't get anyting. Was it a suggestion or answer?

Comment: When you want to store object, Class used to write object should implement serializable. Object should have some valid contents to write into the file For example

Cat c=new Cat();
c.breedtype("Xyz");
c.breedheight(2);
if i write object c into file it will have some valid object contents. Similarly for your program info object should contains some valid PersonInfo objects list in it  without that info arraylist object will be empty and it does not contain any valid PersonInfo object. Add some PersonInfo object into the list and check the behavior

Comment: Mohan Raj , so does it mean that I should serialize and deserialize object? Also, as you can see in my main class, the objects have valid content, if you check this line: info.add(personInfo);, its adding the object with info. However, I have tried igreen's answer, it doesn't do anything. I don't know why. I think I have something to concern about the code inside case block, what do you think?

Comment: Yes you are adding it to list but the call to write object invoke earlier in the code when it does not have anything.  Writeobject code should come once valid contents are added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like that:

```
public void writeFile(List<PersonInfo> information) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BankFile3.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(information);
        os.flush();
        fos.close();
        os.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<PersonInfo> readFile() {
    List<PersonInfo> dataFromFile = null;
    try {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BankFile3.txt");
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        dataFromFile = (List<PersonInfo>) is.readObject();
        fis.close();
        is.close();

        //return readFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataFromFile;

}
```

The class `PesonInfo` should look like:

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
 public class PersonInfo implements Serializable {
   ...
 }
```

and I am using this code to run it:

```
 new ObjectWriter().writeFile(Lists.newArrayList(new PersonInfo("kuku")));
 List<PersonInfo> personInfos = new ObjectWriter().readFile();
 System.out.println(personInfos);
```

Comment: igreen &EpicPandaForce, I tried this. Doesn't do anything. Still not writing and reading file. So do I really need to serialize and deserialize? And I guess I have something to do in my main class. Right now the method calling is outside the loop? Is it supposed to be like this?